# Conditonal expectation on independent random variables

Tags: probability

If I have two independent random variables X and Y. Is the probability $p(X|Y=k) = p(X)$? I am not sure when this statement becomes invalid and what conditions are needed to say its valid.

Also in this case is $p(X|Y<k) = p(X)$.

Comment: What do you understand by $p(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p_{X|Y}$ be the conditional density of $X$ given $Y$, $p_{X,Y}(x,y)$ be their joint density, and $p_X$ and $p_y$ be their marginals. Recall that:

$$
p_{X|Y}(x | y) = \frac{p_{X,Y}(x,y)}{p_Y(y)}
$$

And that $X$ and $Y$ are independent variables if and only if

$$
p_{X,Y}(x,y) = p_X(x)p_Y(y)
$$

From here, what do you think the answer to your first part is? Can you use this to say anything about the second?

Comment: Since $X$ and $Y$ are given to be _random variables_ and not events, this answer is nonsensical.

Comment: @DilipSarwate oh, yeah, whoops, let me rewrite that.